# mysql procedure syntax failure

Tags: mysql

I have problems with my first MySQL procedure. I can't find the syntax failure. This is the body of the procedure:

```
DECLARE TerminId INT;

INSERT INTO `Termin` (`Beginn`, `Ende`, `Titel`, `Ganztaegig`, `Serie`, 
                      `Bemerkung`, `Tooltip`, `Ort`, `Gruppe`, `UserId`) 
VALUES (BeginnPara, EndePara, TitelPara, GanztaegigPara, SeriePara, 
        BemerkungPara, TooltipPara, OrtPara, GruppePara, UserIdPara);

SET TerminId = ( SELECT Distinct Id FROM Termin 
                 where Beginn = BeginnPara 
                       and Ende = EndePara 
                       and UserId = UserIdPara);
```

Comment: unfortuanatley its german: there are no information except a failure occured and the syntax seems to be wrong.

Comment: Just add it. Perhaps your last query does not return a single value?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE TerminId INT; INSERT INTO Termin(Beginn, Ende, Titel, Ganztaegig, Seri' at line 1

Comment: when i execute the sql-statement in the consola it works -> 'DISTINCT' ...

Comment: Script: DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertTermin;
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTermin(BeginnPara DATETIME,EndePara DATETIME, GanztaegigPara TINYINT,SeriePara TINYINT, BemerkungPara VARCHAR(254), TooltipPara VARCHAR(80), OrtPara VARCHAR(2), GruppePara VARCHAR(25), UserIdPara INT, VeranstaltungsTypIdPara INT, AusstattungPara INT)
BEGIN 
DECLARE Titel VARCHAR(40);
DECLARE Veranstaltungstyp VARCHAR(40);
DECLARE TerminId INT;
SET Veranstaltungstyp = (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM VeranstaltungsTyp where Id = VeranstaltungsTypIdPara);
SET TitelPara = GruppePara + ', ' + Veranstaltungstyp;
INsert...
END no change

Answer (score 1):

Delete simple quote

```
  DECLARE TerminId INT;

    INSERT INTO Termin(Beginn, Ende, Titel, Ganztaegig, Serie, Bemerkung, Tooltip, Ort, Gruppe, UserId) VALUES (BeginnPara, EndePara, TitelPara, GanztaegigPara, SeriePara, BemerkungPara, TooltipPara, OrtPara, GruppePara, UserIdPara);

    SET TerminId= (SELECT Distinct Id FROM Termin where Beginn = BeginnPara and Ende = EndePara and UserId = UserIdPara having row_number <= 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE TerminId INT;
INSERT INTO `Termin`(`Beginn`, `Ende`, `Titel`, `Ganztaegig`, `Serie`, `Bemerkung`, `Tooltip`, `Ort`, `Gruppe`, `UserId`) VALUES (BeginnPara, EndePara, TitelPara, GanztaegigPara, SeriePara, BemerkungPara, TooltipPara, OrtPara, GruppePara, UserIdPara);

SELECT Distinct Id INTO TerminId FROM Termin where Beginn = BeginnPara and Ende = EndePara and UserId = UserIdPara having row_number <= 1);
```

Regards.